# Setting a variable within an if statement - JQuery

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement, scope

I'm trying to set a variable within an if statement but for some reason it isn't working! I'm really bad with JQuery/Javascript, so I was hoping someone could help. Here's the code I'm working with:

```
if($("#myicon").hasClass('opacity0')) {
var variable = 1;
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

EDIT: I should add that I'm trying to use this along with charts.js to make a doughnut chart. So, for example

```
var doughnutData = [
        {
            value: variable,
            color:"#000000"
        }
    ];
```

If I manually say "value: 1," it works. But when I try to set it using a variable it doesn't create a chart.

Comment: You mean you're really bad with **JavaScript**, not **Java**. They're completely different. What do you mean it's not working? Please provide more detail by updating your question.

Comment: Your class name isn't valid. It should start with a letter not a number.

Comment: My bad! Also, I tried switching the class to opacity0 and it didn't change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable within the if statement just is used for itself(local variable).

You should declare this variable above the if statement.

```
var variable;

if($("#myicon").hasClass('opacity0')) {
    variable = 1;
}

var doughnutData = [
    {
        value: variable,
        color:"#000000"
    }
];
```

Hope it helpful!

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to access `variable` elsewhere in you code then just drop the `var` so that you're not declaring it on the local scope.

Global variables are not the ideal way to code but without seeing the rest of your code I can't suggest much more